# Never ending nested loop! But why?

Tags: c++, loops

Hey all I am still new to c++.  I'm going into a nested for loop and it seems like the loop variable never gets incremented at the end of the loop.  Here is some code.

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int i,j, m, k;
    k = 2000;
    l = 1000;

    for(i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<l; j++)
        {
            printf("Processing bob %d \n", i * j);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The console output is:

Processing bob 0

Processing bob 0

Processing bob 0

indefinitely..

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not try stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: Suggestion, if you have 3 layers of nested loops, something should be abstracted out into a function or similar.

Comment: I'm using gedit on linux, I don't have a debugger

Comment: the loop incrementers are defined above the code block int i = 0; int j = 0; sorry i did not include that.

Comment: Note that `i * j` will be 0 until the second iteration of the outer loop, because i is 0 and hence `i * j` is 0. Try printing `i` and `j` separately to make it less confusing.

Comment: @AndyMason: If your on Linux, you probably do have a debugger. Likely gdb.

Comment: if you have gcc, you almost certainly have gdb.

Comment: The correct way to combine `i` and `j` would be `j + i*billy.cols`. Also, if there's another problem, modify the code so it's a minimal example (see http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) and post that.

Comment: What are the types of `i`, `j`, `billy.rows` and `billy.cols`?

Comment: I'm brand new to c++, and have never used linux before.  I've programmed java and c# for 5 years.  I honestly am not sure how to use the gdb debugger and also can't find an IDE capable of doing what I need. Well I'm sure they are capable but I've tried both eclipse and code::blocks and ended up troubleshooting them for 4 hours instead of doing homework.

Comment: Don't drop type declarations!

Comment: I declared my identifiers above the code block given as I've previously stated.

Comment: @AndyMason if you have missed something out in your question, you can edit it.

Comment: Haha, jack is the reason i is not declared in the for loop actually.  I'll just paste the whole thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first iterations of the loop, while `i == 0`, `i * j` will also equal 0, whatever `j` is.

Comment: Bingo, maybe I should at least get a cup of coffee in before I start coding in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to declare your variable's type in the for loop, that is you need:

`for (int i = 0; i < billow.rows; i++) { ... }`

and similarly for `j`.

Comment: It is mentioned in the (big pile of) comments that `i` and `j` are already declared. This would have been a compiler error if they weren't previously declared anyway.